# T-SQL View to select FULL OUTER JOIN and add additional rows on "A" based on "B" table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, view

I hope someone can help me.

I need to solve a problem with a view that get me the correct result based in the following scenario.

I have two tables: `Language` and `ReportDescription`

**Language**

```
Id   Tag  Description  
---- ---- ----------------
1    en   English     
2    de   German  
3    fr   French  
4    it   Italian
```

**ReportDescription**

```
LanguageId ReportId    Description  
---------- ----------- -------------------
1          1           Committee of (Eng)  
2          1           Committee of (German)  
3          1           Committee of (French)  
4          1           Committee of (Ita)  
1          2           Appointment of (Eng)
```

The result I'd like to have it would be:

```
LanguageId ReportId    Description  
---------- ----------- -------------------
1          1           Committee of (Eng)  
2          1           Committee of (German)  
3          1           Committee of (French)  
4          1           Committee of (Ita)  
1          2           Appointment of (Eng)  
2          2           Appointment of (Eng)  
3          2           Appointment of (Eng)  
4          2           Appointment of (Eng)
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Why does the result have a row for `Appointment of (Eng)` in Italian?

Comment: It might help if you describe exactly what you're after with the result set, in prose. Right now i cannot quite tell...

Comment: @Paul: agree. What is the logic to produce result 3. There are at least 2 ways of doing this but without the logic any solution kay fail in other cases

Answer (score 0):

This one returns the result you describe, hope that's what you want.

It will take a `FallbackDescription` if this entry does not exist in `ReportDescription`.

```
SELECT
  l.id LanguageId, r.ReportId,
  COALESCE( rd.Description, r.FallbackDescription ) Description
FROM language l
JOIN ( SELECT ReportId, MIN(Description) FallbackDescription
       FROM ReportDescription
       GROUP BY ReportId ) r ON ( 1 = 1 )
LEFT JOIN ReportDescription rd ON ( rd.Id = l.Id AND rd.ReportId = r.ReportId )
ORDER BY ReportId, LanguageId
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a default Report when not available in especific language, this query will do it:

```
SELECT rd.LanguageId, rd.ReportId, 
 COALESCE(r.Description, 
   (SELECT Description FROM ReportDescription
    WHERE ReportDescription.ReportId = rd.ReportId AND LanguageId = 1)) AS Description
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ReportId, l.Id AS LanguageId FROM ReportDescription, Language l) rd
LEFT JOIN ReportDescription r ON rd.LanguageId = r.LanguageId AND rd.ReportId = r.ReportId
ORDER BY rd.ReportId, rd.LanguageId
```

The default language seems to be english in your question (do not forget to add spanish support ;-) ).